# Check if write was successful or failed

Tags: php, mongodb

Using Mongo 3.2 with PHP, how can I check to see if a write was successful?

```
$client = new MongoDB\Client('mongodb://connection');

$values = array('name'=>'Jason', 'prod' => 'true');
$result = $client->mn->users->insertOne($values);
```

What do I need to check for in `$result` to see if write succeeded or failed?

Comment: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.insertOne/ $result should have 2 values write concern and _id. And this document explains everything better.

Comment: @user10, yup, how do I access it? everything appears to be in a private method in $result.

Comment: i guess $result should be an array and $result['_id'] should give the value. But i'm not sure. I have not tried it. I'm saying this from that document.

Answer (score 0):

Try the code below:-

```
$client = new MongoDB\Client('mongodb://connection');    
$values = array('name'=>'Jason', 'prod' => 'true');
$result = $client->mn->users->insertOne($values);    
var_dump($result->_id);
```